# How can I find the full dot-separated key when searching a nested object via the value?

Tags: javascript

Given I have some object with nested objects:

```
const someDataObject = {
    places: {
        earthKingdom: {
            capital: "Ba Sing Se"
        },
        fireNation: {
            capital: "Capital City"
        },
        waterTribe: {
            capital: "North Pole"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to determine the full, dot-separated key of a property by searching via text. So, if I search for "North Pole", My expected outcome would be "places.waterTribe.capital"

How can I write a function that will do this?

Comment: You need to write a nested search function that compares against the input text if the value is a string, and does another search if is an object (you'll probably end up with something recursive). Once you have the keys, for example in an array of strings, you can join them on the . dot string. Keep in mind that the object keys may also contain dots, so for example `{"some.key": "value"}` may make your output format unusable  (not necessarily, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that using `recursive` function.

Once the function find the value, it will return an arary.

Each step will return of the recursion with `unshift` the key.

```js
function findPath(input, word) {
  for (let key in input) {
    if (input[key] && typeof(input[key]) === "object") {
      const result = findPath(input[key], word);
      if (result) {
        result.unshift(key);
        return result;
      }
    } else if (input[key] === word) {
      return [ key ];
    }
  }
}

const someDataObject = {
  places: {
    earthKingdom: {
      capital: "Ba Sing Se"
    },
    fireNation: {
      capital: "Capital City"
    },
    waterTribe: {
      capital: "North Pole"
    }
  }
}

const path = findPath(someDataObject, "North Pole");
console.log(path.join('.'));
```

Comment: Can you even walk nodes none recursive? It's a genuine question I ask myself every time I end up walking odes recursively.

Comment: That's hard on this tree structure.